# Conservation of quantum information

Tags: particle-physics

Bosons occupy the same quantum states, even if fermions obey Pauli's Exclusion Principle. Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle rules out determining the quantum states occupied by two close fermions, etc....

I mean to say is it impossible in Quantum Mechanics to trace the history, or follow it, of a boson or fermion? There are inevitable errors. Why are we concerned about the loss of information in a black hole, where degeneracy breaks down? I mean, how are two mysteries different, with respect to conservation of information? We have laws of black hole thermodynamics, which prohibit the loss of energy...

Comment: Welcome to PSE! Please, can you take a look on other questions and Meta? You will find some examples on what kind of questions we accept here and how to state them in a clear way. In this case, can you be more clear?